# Close subtasks when parent task is closed in Jira

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile

I'm beginner in Jira, so please sorry for simple question. How I can make Jira close subtasks when parent task is closed. And other way round, when parent task is closed, close all subtasks. I'm trying to do that simple, without ScriptRunner plugin.
I found this plugin: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.innovalog.jmwe.jira-misc-workflow-extensions/cloud/overview. But did't understand how to handle it, and not sure if he can help me.
Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: There is built in post function that can transition parent issue. For the other way around I'd need custom script.

Comment: Hi @Robert I can't find post function option there. Can you please tell me where and what exactly you talking about? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that it is part of JIRA Misc Workflow Extensions plugin

Answer (score 2):

I have a suggestion that doesn't exactly answer your question, but you may find useful.

It is possible to add a *condition* to the parent issue type that will not allow you to transition it to closed while there are still open subtasks. The button for 'Close' will not even be enabled if there are open subtasks and they will not be able to drag it to 'closed' on the task boards.

This indirectly forces the users to close all subtasks.

If you do take this approach, make sure that everyone knows what you have done. Otherwise they may assume there is a permissions problem or a JIRA bug that is stopping them from closing the parent issue.

Comment: Very useful one, but as you mention it little bit not answer on my question. But thanks anyway!